# Firefox Bug?: Getting more content generated & list items

Tags: html, firefox

It seems like with html like

```
<ul id="projectsList" class="list-style-1">
  <li>
    <a href="/projects/view/1">
      <p class="heading">New Project 1</p>
      <p class="desc">by <strong>jiewmeng</strong></p>
      <ul class="meta">
        <li>Your progress <strong>0%</strong></li>
        <li>Project's Progress <strong>0%</strong></li>
        <li>Your tasks due today <strong>0</strong></li>
      </ul>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

firefox adds markup to make it

```
<ul class="list-style-1" id="projectsList">
  <li>
    <a href="/projects/view/1"></a>
    <p class="heading"><a href="/projects/view/1">New Project 1</a></p>
    <a href="/projects/view/1"></a>
    <p class="desc"><a href="/projects/view/1">by <strong>jiewmeng</strong></a></p>
    <a href="/projects/view/1"></a>
    <ul class="meta">
      <a href="/projects/view/1"></a>
      <li><a href="/projects/view/1">Your progress <strong>0%</strong></a></li>
      <a href="/projects/view/1"></a>
      <li><a href="/projects/view/1">Project's Progress <strong>0%</strong></a></li>
      <a href="/projects/view/1"></a>
      <li><a href="/projects/view/1">Your tasks due today <strong>0</strong></a></li>
      <a href="/projects/view/1"></a>
    </ul>
    <a href="/projects/view/1"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I narrowed the problem to the meta list items if I comment out the meta list, it works http://jsfiddle.net/MSegC/2/

I want to use the `<a>` as a block level element as I want the user to be able to click the whole box to enter the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A is not a block level element in html (at least in html 4) so the short story is you can't use it like this :). That's why FF breaks' it for you.

http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html

You should do what you want with an onclick event on the containing block.

Another option seems to be to force the doctype of the page to be html5 since in html5 it is possible for a to be a block level element.

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links

Comment: The doctype won't change this behaviour in Firefox. The browsers parser implementation has to be changed. Firefox 4 has an HTML5-compatible parser and won't exhibit this problem.

Comment: @alohci My bad. You are right. I assumed that it was implied the fact that you can treat a page as html5 compliant only if the browser supports it.

Comment: Ya, I was already having a HTML5 doctype. I guess I will have the user click on the link instead of the whole box then? Or do you suggest something else?

Comment: you can catch the onclick event on the containing div and do a document.location = "<your new href>";

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, `<a>` is not a block-level element, but you can make it into one by setting the `display` property to either `block` or `inline-block`.

`display:block;` should make it act like any other block-level element.

`display:inline-block;` is a half-way house between making it a block-level and an inline element. If `display:block;` makes your page layout go nuts, then use `inline-block` instead.